# Failing to get results with sort query in mgo

Tags: mongodb, mgo

I'm trying to understand what's wrong with my use case. I'm trying to query MongoDB with mgo sort query like this:

```
conn := _Mongo.Connect() // custom mongo connection
defer conn.Close()
c := conn.DB(dbname).C(collname)
index := mgo.Index{
    Key:        skeys,
    Unique:     false,
    Background: true,
}
e := c.EnsureIndex(index)
if e != nil {
   panic(e)
}
err := c.Find(spec).Sort(skeys...).All(&out)
```

As you can see I do call ensure index on my passed selection keys (skeys). But during runtime for large queries I get the following error:

```
Executor error: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.
```

I checked that my collection indeed has an index, but it seems to me that mgo does not use it.

Thanks,
Valentin.

P.S. Here is explain output from mongo for query in question:

```
Explain: bson.M{"queryPlanner":bson.M{"parsedQuery":bson.M{"$and":[]interface {}{bson.M{"das.record":bson.M{"$eq":1}}, bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}}}, "winningPlan":bson.M{"stage":"SORT", "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"FETCH", "filter":bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}, "inputStage":bson.M{"isSparse":false, "isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2, "direction":"forward", "stage":"IXSCAN", "keyPattern":bson.M{"das.record":1}, "indexName":"das.record_1", "isMultiKey":false, "isUnique":false, "indexBounds":bson.M{"das.record":[]interface {}{"[1, 1]"}}}}}}, "rejectedPlans":[]interface {}{bson.M{"stage":"SORT", "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"FETCH", "filter":bson.M{"das.record":bson.M{"$eq":1}}, "inputStage":bson.M{"keyPattern":bson.M{"qhash":1}, "indexName":"qhash_1", "isMultiKey":false, "isSparse":false, "stage":"IXSCAN", "isUnique":false, "isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2, "direction":"forward", "indexBounds":bson.M{"qhash":[]interface {}{"[\"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\", \"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\"]"}}}}}}, bson.M{"stage":"SORT", "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"KEEP_MUTATIONS", "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"FETCH", "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"AND_SORTED", "inputStages":[]interface {}{bson.M{"keyPattern":bson.M{"qhash":1}, "isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2, "indexBounds":bson.M{"qhash":[]interface {}{"[\"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\", \"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\"]"}}, "direction":"forward", "stage":"IXSCAN", "indexName":"qhash_1", "isMultiKey":false, "isUnique":false, "isSparse":false}, bson.M{"stage":"IXSCAN", "isMultiKey":false, "isUnique":false, "isSparse":false, "isPartial":false, "direction":"forward", "indexBounds":bson.M{"das.record":[]interface {}{"[1, 1]"}}, "keyPattern":bson.M{"das.record":1}, "indexName":"das.record_1", "indexVersion":2}}}}}}}, bson.M{"sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"FETCH", "filter":bson.M{"$and":[]interface {}{bson.M{"das.record":bson.M{"$eq":1}}, bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}}}, "inputStage":bson.M{"direction":"forward", "keyPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "indexName":"dataset.name_1", "isMultiKey":true, "isSparse":false, "indexBounds":bson.M{"dataset.name":[]interface {}{"[MinKey, MaxKey]"}}, "stage":"IXSCAN", "isUnique":false, "isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2}}}, "stage":"SORT"}}, "plannerVersion":1, "namespace":"das.cache", "indexFilterSet":false}, "executionStats":bson.M{"executionTimeMillis":317, "totalDocsExamined":30972, "executionSuccess":false, "errorMessage":"Exec error resulting in state FAILURE :: caused by :: errmsg: \"Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.\"", "totalKeysExamined":30972, "executionStages":bson.M{"isEOF":0, "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "needTime":30973, "saveState":497, "nReturned":0, "restoreState":497, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":150, "memLimit":33554432, "advanced":0, "needYield":0, "invalidates":0, "memUsage":33554660, "inputStage":bson.M{"advanced":30972, "needTime":1, "saveState":497, "restoreState":497, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"FETCH", "works":30972, "restoreState":497, "invalidates":0, "alreadyHasObj":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"dupsDropped":0, "seenInvalidated":0, "stage":"IXSCAN", "needTime":0, "isMultiKey":false, "indexBounds":bson.M{"das.record":[]interface {}{"[1, 1]"}}, "keysExamined":30972, "direction":"forward", "restoreState":497, "isEOF":0, "indexName":"das.record_1", "isSparse":false, "indexVersion":2, "seeks":1, "dupsTested":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":35, "advanced":30972, "needYield":0, "saveState":497, "keyPattern":bson.M{"das.record":1}, "nReturned":30972, "works":30972, "invalidates":0, "isUnique":false, "isPartial":false}, "saveState":497, "filter":bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}, "advanced":30972, "isEOF":0, "docsExamined":30972, "nReturned":30972, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":68, "needTime":0, "needYield":0}, "stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "nReturned":30972, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":138, "works":30973, "needYield":0}, "stage":"SORT", "works":30974}, "allPlansExecution":[]interface {}{bson.M{"nReturned":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":69, "totalKeysExamined":10491, "totalDocsExamined":10491, "executionStages":bson.M{"stage":"SORT", "executionTimeMillisEstimate":69, "works":10492, "restoreState":335, "isEOF":0, "memUsage":11812527, "inputStage":bson.M{"advanced":10491, "needTime":1, "saveState":335, "restoreState":335, "isEOF":0, "stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "executionTimeMillisEstimate":69, "works":10492, "invalidates":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"needTime":0, "invalidates":0, "isEOF":0, "docsExamined":10491, "alreadyHasObj":0, "stage":"FETCH", "filter":bson.M{"das.record":bson.M{"$eq":1}}, "advanced":10491, "needYield":0, "saveState":335, "inputStage":bson.M{"invalidates":0, "isMultiKey":false, "seeks":1, "dupsTested":0, "needTime":0, "isEOF":0, "works":10491, "needYield":0, "restoreState":335, "keyPattern":bson.M{"qhash":1}, "indexName":"qhash_1", "isSparse":false, "stage":"IXSCAN", "nReturned":10491, "seenInvalidated":0, "indexVersion":2, "indexBounds":bson.M{"qhash":[]interface {}{"[\"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\", \"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\"]"}}, "advanced":10491, "isPartial":false, "isUnique":false, "direction":"forward", "keysExamined":10491, "dupsDropped":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":10, "saveState":335}, "nReturned":10491, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":55, "works":10491, "restoreState":335}, "nReturned":10491, "needYield":0}, "needTime":10492, "memLimit":33554432, "nReturned":0, "advanced":0, "needYield":0, "saveState":335, "invalidates":0, "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}}}, bson.M{"nReturned":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":11, "totalKeysExamined":10491, "totalDocsExamined":5245, "executionStages":bson.M{"restoreState":335, "inputStage":bson.M{"saveState":335, "restoreState":335, "inputStage":bson.M{"nReturned":5245, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":11, "advanced":5245, "needYield":0, "restoreState":335, "invalidates":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"isEOF":0, "alreadyHasObj":0, "works":10491, "needTime":5246, "restoreState":335, "advanced":5245, "saveState":335, "nReturned":5245, "needYield":0, "invalidates":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"AND_SORTED", "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0, "works":10491, "saveState":335, "advanced":5245, "needTime":5246, "nReturned":5245, "needYield":0, "isEOF":0, "flagged":0, "restoreState":335, "invalidates":0, "failedAnd_0":0, "failedAnd_1":0, "inputStages":[]interface {}{bson.M{"stage":"IXSCAN", "nReturned":5246, "invalidates":0, "isUnique":false, "keysExamined":5246, "dupsDropped":0, "seeks":1, "dupsTested":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0, "advanced":5246, "restoreState":335, "keyPattern":bson.M{"qhash":1}, "indexName":"qhash_1", "indexVersion":2, "indexBounds":bson.M{"qhash":[]interface {}{"[\"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\", \"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\"]"}}, "needTime":0, "needYield":0, "saveState":335, "isEOF":0, "isMultiKey":false, "direction":"forward", "works":5246, "isSparse":false, "isPartial":false, "seenInvalidated":0}, bson.M{"advanced":5245, "isEOF":0, "indexBounds":bson.M{"das.record":[]interface {}{"[1, 1]"}}, "seeks":1, "stage":"IXSCAN", "nReturned":5245, "needTime":0, "needYield":0, "isSparse":false, "indexVersion":2, "isPartial":false, "direction":"forward", "executionTimeMillisEstimate":0, "works":5245, "saveState":335, "invalidates":0, "keyPattern":bson.M{"das.record":1}, "isMultiKey":false, "keysExamined":5245, "restoreState":335, "indexName":"das.record_1", "isUnique":false, "dupsTested":0, "dupsDropped":0, "seenInvalidated":0}}}, "stage":"FETCH", "executionTimeMillisEstimate":11, "docsExamined":5245}, "stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "works":10492, "needTime":5247, "saveState":335, "isEOF":0}, "stage":"KEEP_MUTATIONS", "nReturned":5245, "needYield":0, "needTime":5247, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":11, "works":10492, "advanced":5245}, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":11, "works":10492, "needYield":0, "invalidates":0, "memUsage":6102195, "stage":"SORT", "nReturned":0, "advanced":0, "needTime":10492, "saveState":335, "isEOF":0, "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "memLimit":33554432}}, bson.M{"nReturned":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":70, "totalKeysExamined":10491, "totalDocsExamined":10491, "executionStages":bson.M{"executionTimeMillisEstimate":70, "saveState":335, "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "works":10492, "inputStage":bson.M{"advanced":10485, "needYield":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":58, "works":10492, "needTime":7, "saveState":335, "restoreState":335, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"executionTimeMillisEstimate":36, "saveState":335, "docsExamined":10491, "nReturned":10485, "restoreState":335, "invalidates":0, "needYield":0, "filter":bson.M{"$and":[]interface {}{bson.M{"das.record":bson.M{"$eq":1}}, bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}}}, "advanced":10485, "alreadyHasObj":0, "stage":"FETCH", "needTime":6, "isEOF":0, "inputStage":bson.M{"keyPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2, "nReturned":10491, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":24, "advanced":10491, "saveState":335, "invalidates":0, "indexBounds":bson.M{"dataset.name":[]interface {}{"[MinKey, MaxKey]"}}, "dupsDropped":0, "seenInvalidated":0, "dupsTested":10491, "works":10491, "needTime":0, "isMultiKey":true, "isUnique":false, "keysExamined":10491, "needYield":0, "isEOF":0, "direction":"forward", "seeks":1, "stage":"IXSCAN", "restoreState":335, "indexName":"dataset.name_1", "isSparse":false}, "works":10491}, "stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "nReturned":10485}, "stage":"SORT", "nReturned":0, "advanced":0, "memUsage":11787104, "needTime":10492, "needYield":0, "restoreState":335, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "memLimit":33554432}}, bson.M{"executionTimeMillisEstimate":59, "totalKeysExamined":10491, "totalDocsExamined":10491, "executionStages":bson.M{"works":10492, "advanced":0, "needTime":10492, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, "restoreState":335, "memUsage":11812527, "inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", "works":10492, "advanced":10491, "inputStage":bson.M{"inputStage":bson.M{"isMultiKey":false, "isSparse":false, "indexBounds":bson.M{"das.record":[]interface {}{"[1, 1]"}}, "seeks":1, "advanced":10491, "needTime":0, "saveState":335, "indexName":"das.record_1", "dupsTested":0, "restoreState":335, "isPartial":false, "dupsDropped":0, "isUnique":false, "indexVersion":2, "direction":"forward", "keysExamined":10491, "stage":"IXSCAN", "nReturned":10491, "needYield":0, "isEOF":0, "seenInvalidated":0, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":11, "works":10491, "invalidates":0, "keyPattern":bson.M{"das.record":1}}, "stage":"FETCH", "works":10491, "advanced":10491, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "alreadyHasObj":0, "filter":bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}, "nReturned":10491, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":21, "needTime":0, "needYield":0, "saveState":335, "restoreState":335, "docsExamined":10491}, "saveState":335, "restoreState":335, "isEOF":0, "invalidates":0, "nReturned":10491, "executionTimeMillisEstimate":47, "needTime":1, "needYield":0}, "stage":"SORT", "executionTimeMillisEstimate":59, "needYield":0, "nReturned":0, "saveState":335, "memLimit":33554432}, "nReturned":0}}, "errorCode":96, "nReturned":0}, "serverInfo":bson.M{"version":"3.6.3", "gitVersion":"9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5", "host":"vkair", "port":8230}}
```

In particular, it says:

```
"inputStage":bson.M{"direction":"forward", "keyPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1},
"indexName":"dataset.name_1", "isMultiKey":true, "isSparse":false, 
"indexBounds":bson.M{"dataset.name":[]interface {}{"[MinKey, MaxKey]"}},     
"stage":"IXSCAN", "isUnique":false, "isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2}}}, 
"stage":"SORT"}}, 
"plannerVersion":1, "namespace":"das.cache", "indexFilterSet":false}, 
"executionStats":bson.M{"executionTimeMillis":317, "totalDocsExamined":30972,
"executionSuccess":false,
"errorMessage":"Exec error resulting in state FAILURE :: caused by :: errmsg: \"Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.
```

P.S.S. The winning plan was (output from mgo):

```
"winningPlan":bson.M{"stage":"SORT", 
"sortPattern":bson.M{"dataset.name":1}, 
"inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"SORT_KEY_GENERATOR", 
"inputStage":bson.M{"stage":"FETCH", 
"filter":bson.M{"qhash":bson.M{"$eq":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"}}, 
"inputStage":bson.M{"isSparse":false, 
"isPartial":false, "indexVersion":2, 
"direction":"forward", "stage":"IXSCAN", 
"keyPattern":bson.M{"das.record":1}, 
"indexName":"das.record_1",
"isMultiKey":false, "isUnique":false, 
"indexBounds":bson.M{"das.record":[]interface {}{"[1, 1]"}}}}}}
```

and, output from mongo shell

```
                "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "sortPattern" : {
                            "dataset.name" : 1
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "filter" : {
                                            "qhash" : {
                                                    "$eq" : "7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"
                                            }
                                    },
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "das.record" : 1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "das.record_1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "isUnique" : false,
                                            "isSparse" : false,
                                            "isPartial" : false,
                                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "das.record" : [
                                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                                    ]
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            }
```

As far as I can tell the winning plans from mgo and mongo shell are the same. If I execute the same query in mongo shell I get the following:

```
> db.cache.find({"qhash":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133", "das.record":1}).sort({"dataset.name":1})
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Executor error during find command: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.",
    "code" : 96,
    "codeName" : "OperationFailed"}
```

while if I do count aggregation, it returns results fast:

```
db.cache.find({"qhash":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133", "das.record":1}).sort({"dataset.name":1}).count()
69936
```

so it seems like mongo itself has a problem with using winning plan (index) while fetching results.

**update1**
As Wan suggested I created new compound index

```
db.cache.createIndex({"qhash":1, "das.record":1, "dataset.name":1})
```

but it didn't solve the problem. If I place the query

```
db.cache.find({"qhash":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133", "das.record":1}).sort({"dataset.name":1}).explain()
```

the winning plan is still uses `das.record` index, see

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
            "plannerVersion" : 1,
            "namespace" : "das.cache",
            "indexFilterSet" : false,
            "parsedQuery" : {
                    "$and" : [
                            {
                                    "das.record" : {
                                            "$eq" : 1
                                    }
                            },
                            {
                                    "qhash" : {
                                            "$eq" : "7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"
                                    }
                            }
                    ]
            },
            "winningPlan" : {
                    "stage" : "SORT",
                    "sortPattern" : {
                            "dataset.name" : 1
                    },
                    "inputStage" : {
                            "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "FETCH",
                                    "filter" : {
                                            "qhash" : {
                                                    "$eq" : "7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"
                                            }
                                    },
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                            "keyPattern" : {
                                                    "das.record" : 1
                                            },
                                            "indexName" : "das.record_1",
                                            "isMultiKey" : false,
                                            "isUnique" : false,
                                            "isSparse" : false,
                                            "isPartial" : false,
                                            "indexVersion" : 2,
                                            "direction" : "forward",
                                            "indexBounds" : {
                                                    "das.record" : [
                                                            "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                                    ]
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            },
            "rejectedPlans" : [
                    {
                            "stage" : "SORT",
                            "sortPattern" : {
                                    "dataset.name" : 1
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                                            "filter" : {
                                                    "das.record" : {
                                                            "$eq" : 1
                                                    }
                                            },
                                            "inputStage" : {
                                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                                            "qhash" : 1
                                                    },
                                                    "indexName" : "qhash_1",
                                                    "isMultiKey" : false,
                                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                                            "qhash" : [
                                                                    "[\"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\", \"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\"]"
                                                            ]
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    {
                            "stage" : "SORT",
                            "sortPattern" : {
                                    "dataset.name" : 1
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                                            "inputStage" : {
                                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                                            "qhash" : 1,
                                                            "das.record" : 1,
                                                            "dataset.name" : 1
                                                    },
                                                    "indexName" : "qhash_1_das.record_1_dataset.name_1",
                                                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                                            "qhash" : [
                                                                    "[\"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\", \"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133\"]"
                                                            ],
                                                            "das.record" : [
                                                                    "[1.0, 1.0]"
                                                            ],
                                                            "dataset.name" : [
                                                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                            ]
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                    {
                            "stage" : "SORT",
                            "sortPattern" : {
                                    "dataset.name" : 1
                            },
                            "inputStage" : {
                                    "stage" : "SORT_KEY_GENERATOR",
                                    "inputStage" : {
                                            "stage" : "FETCH",
                                            "filter" : {
                                                    "$and" : [
                                                            {
                                                                    "das.record" : {
                                                                            "$eq" : 1
                                                                    }
                                                            },
                                                            {
                                                                    "qhash" : {
                                                                            "$eq" : "7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133"
                                                                    }
                                                            }
                                                    ]
                                            },
                                            "inputStage" : {
                                                    "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                                    "keyPattern" : {
                                                            "dataset.name" : 1
                                                    },
                                                    "indexName" : "dataset.name_1",
                                                    "isMultiKey" : true,
                                                    "isUnique" : false,
                                                    "isSparse" : false,
                                                    "isPartial" : false,
                                                    "indexVersion" : 2,
                                                    "direction" : "forward",
                                                    "indexBounds" : {
                                                            "dataset.name" : [
                                                                    "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                            ]
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            ]
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
            "host" : "vkair",
            "port" : 8230,
            "version" : "3.6.3",
            "gitVersion" : "9586e557d54ef70f9ca4b43c26892cd55257e1a5"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of [explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/) from `mongo` shell please ?  The output of the `explain` will help you debug whether it's actually using index(es) See also [Explain Results](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/)

Comment: Wan, I updated the issue and added requested explain plan.

Comment: It seems like a MongoDB bug: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10472

Comment: Thanks for the updated information for explain outputs. In regards to bug SERVER-10472, I don't think your question is related to it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Executor error: OperationFailed: Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.

In MongoDB, sort operations can obtain the sort order by retrieving documents based on the ordering in an index. If the query planner cannot obtain the sort order from an index, it will sort the results in memory. Using an index to retrieve results in sorted order is more efficient than retrieving results and sorting in-memory. In addition, sort operations that do not use an index will abort when they use 32 megabytes of memory.

Based on the output of `explain` you posted, this is because you have an index on `das.record` (winning plan, used for the query), however you're sorting based on `dataset.name` which either a) losing plan or b) there is no such index.

[An index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/) can support sort operations on a non-prefix subset of the index key pattern. To do so, the query must include equality conditions on all the prefix keys that precede the sort keys. For example, if your query is :

```
db.cache.find({"qhash":"7b32b92becab9b5de06fa8ac85011133", "das.record":1}).sort({"dataset.name":1})
```

Then to utilise index for both filter and sort, you should have a [compound index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/):

```
{"qhash":1, "das.record":1, "dataset.name":1 }
```

See more information on the manual [Tutorial: sort and non-prefix subset of an index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/#sort-and-non-prefix-subset-of-an-index)

You may also benefit from reading: [MongoDB Indexing Strategies](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/indexes/) and [Blog: Optimizing MongoDB Compound Indexes](https://emptysqua.re/blog/optimizing-mongodb-compound-indexes/)

> As far as I can tell the winning plans from mgo and mongo shell are the same

Given the same query the output should be the same. The reason I asked for output from the `mongo` shell is to remove the `Go` aspect, i.e. your code from the debugging layer.

**UPDATE**:

> I created additional index { "v" : 2, "key" : { "qhash" : 1, "das.record" : 1, "dataset.name" : 1 }, "name" : "qhash_1_das.record_1_dataset.name_1", "ns" : "das.cache" } but the MongoDB does not use it

Based on your explain output, you can find that the new index `qhash_1_das.record_1_dataset.name_1` is listed under the `rejectedPlan` section. There are few potential reasons for this, but the likely cause in this case is that `dataset.name` is an array or has some array value. Indicated by `isMultiKey:true` and the index bound of `min, max`.

This [multikey index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-multikey/) on `dataset.name` may have caused an undesired slowness, hence being rejected as the fastest query plan.

If you don't intend to have value of arrays in `dataset.name`, find the offending documents and alter/remove the array values. In addition, you also need to recreate index `qhash_1_das.record_1_dataset.name_1`.

If `dataset.name` actually contains arrays, sorting based on multi key is going to be less performant. You may have to remove the other indexes, choose another field with single value to sort, manipulate split the value of `dataset.name`, or redesign your `dataset` document structure.

Comment: Wan, I'll accept this explanation if it will work. But it does not. I created additional index  {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "qhash" : 1,
                        "das.record" : 1,
                        "dataset.name" : 1
                },
                "name" : "qhash_1_das.record_1_dataset.name_1",
                "ns" : "das.cache"
        } but the MongoDB does not use it. The explain still uses das.record:1 win. plan.

Comment: My point is that I need all indexes: individual qhash and das.record as well as compound. But it seems to me that MongoDB uses only individual one even if compound is present. I wish I can specify which index to use.

Comment: Hi @Valentin, could you elaborate why you would need the `qhash` individual index? indexes can use a prefix. Please see the links provided in the answer to find out more. If after adding the index suggested and it still "does not work" (I assumed it means still not sorting using index?). could you please update your question with 1) the query and 2) the explain output ? Cheers.

Comment: I have three use cases to cover: 1. I query records by their qhash. 2. I need to find valid records by using das.record index 3. I want to get sorted list of records which has specific qhash and are valid (das.record=1). As you can see #1 I need qhash individual index, for #2 I need individual das.record index and for #3 I need an index which will efficiently find records and sort them out.

Comment: and, yes "still does not work" means the sorting does not use compound index, instead it uses individual index.

Comment: I updated the issue and put new explain plan output.

Comment: @Valentin, i've updated the answer according to your recent explain output. thanks